# How can I solve catkin error: "use of old-style cast"?

Tags: ros, catkin, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin gives me an error on some third-party header files, which I included in my code. The error message says, the code was using old-style casts.
I know, that the error results from the compiler option `-Werror=old-style-cast`, but I wasn't able to find an easy workaround without removing the flag from my CMakeLists.txt.
I would like to allow old-style casts temporarily by passing the right compiler option to `catkin_make` or `catkin build`, but all my attempts have failed so far.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257746/how-can-i-solve-catkin-error:-%22use-of-old-style-cast%22?/) by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 775 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/201694/how-do-i-set-global-cmake-flags-catkin/) helped me, to find a solution for my problem:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wno-error=old-style-cast"
```

This also works with `catkin build`.

A permanent fix would have been to just remove the `-Werror=old-style-cast` from my own CMakeLists.txt, of course. But I preferred to have a quick workaround to see, whether my code compiles in general and afterwards potentially go on and fix the third party code.

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1